# Ruby Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have to include Bootstrap DateTimePicker to my university project but I've tried and nothing happened. I used this [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails/0.0.11/frames) and did:

- added `gem 'bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails'` to Gemfile and run `bundle install`
- added `//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker` to `application.js`

Wiev:

```
   <div id="container">
  <center>
    <p>
      <strong>First name:</strong>
      <%= Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).first_name%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Last name:</strong>
      <%= Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id]).last_name%>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Doctor spec:</strong>
      <%= Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id]).spec%>
    </p>

<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >

<%= submit_tag "Check", :name => nil %>
  </center>
  </div>
```

Now I see only input on my site, there is no calendar button which allow me to choose date and time.

`application.js`:

```
   // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .
 $(document).on("click","[data-behaviour~=datepicker]",function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
  });
```

LayOut(Here was an error ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<title>Student - Zaklad Opieki Zdrowotnej</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application',media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="header">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <h1><a href="#">ZOZ Student</a></h1>
      <p>Twoja najblizsza i ulubiona przychodnia</p>
      <p>Latwe zarzadzanie poprzez Internet!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right"><a href="#"><img src="/images/demo/banner.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="topbar">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <p>Adres: Rzeszow, ul. Wincentego Pola 17/1</p>
      <p>Tel: +48 175534322 | Mail: kontakt@zoz.pl</p>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to 'O nas', welcome_index_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Nasze poradnie oraz przychodnie', welcome_index2_path %></li>
        <li><a href="#">Panel zarzadzania dla lekarzy i pracownikow</a>
          <ul>
            <%= render 'welcome/form' %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="container">
  <%= yield %>
  </div>

  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
 <div id="homecontent">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>System zarzadzania juz otwarty</h2>
        <img class="imgl" src="/images/demo/x1.gif" alt="" />
        <p>Dzieki internetowemu systemowi zarzadzania nasi lekarze w latwy sposob moga kontrolowowac, tworzyc i edytowac rejestracje, wizyty a co za tym idzie pacjenci poinformowani sa o wszystkim na biezaco droga elektroniczna. Ulatwi to z pewnoscia kontakt z pacjentami jak i usprawni funkcjonowanie calego systemu.<p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Nowo otwarte przychodnie</h2>
        <img class="imgl" src="/images/demo/x2.gif" alt="" />
        <p>Jest nam bardzo milo poinformowac, ze nasz Zaklad Opieki Zdrowotnej podpisal umowe z trzema nowymi przychodniami. Co za tym idzie pacjenci moga skorzystac u nas z uslug wykwalifikowanych stomatologow, neurologow oraz psychologow.<p>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
        <h2>Liczba pacjentow rosnie!</h2>
        <img class="imgl" src="/images/demo/x3.gif" alt="" />
        <p>Cieszymy sie, ze z naszych uslug korzysta coraz wiecej pacjentow. Swiadczy to o naszej profesjonalnej kadrze oraz wykwalifikowanych specjalistach. Wciaz staramy sie zwiekszyc zakres naszych uslug aby kazdy znalazl u nas to czego potrzebuje. Wkrotce otwarcie nowych przychodni!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="imageline">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="/images/demo/1.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/demo/2.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/demo/3.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/demo/4.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li class="last"><img src="/images/demo/5.gif" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->

  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="copyright">
    <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2014 - <a href="#">L15 Team</a></p>
    <p class="fl_right">Strona przygotowana na potrzeby projektu</p>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <br class="clear" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have used exactly the code given in example so i don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Did you restart your server after bundle?

Comment: update question with your exact `application.js` want to see exactly where did you added your bootstrap

Comment: Nothing happened after restart, I am new in Ruby so I can make funny mistakes :)

Comment: @user3742883 are there any errors in developer console? when you try to select it

Comment: what about bundle install?

Comment: bundle install installed this gem

Comment: when I'm debugging I don't see any errors

Comment: @user3742883 where have you written your js code? Put it inside your application.js or make a new js file for datepicker and require it inside your application.js

Comment: @user3742883 also put a simple `alert("working");` inside your js function at first line to see if this function is being executed or not

Comment: I never working with java script so I don't know how to do this :(

Comment: @user3742883 what did you do? did you alert inside your function? Did it work?

Comment: I don't say that I need this datetime picker, but I have to include any in my project

Comment: @user3742883 update your question by what you tried now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go through the steps of using [bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails/0.0.11/frames)

a. Add `gem 'bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails'` inside your **gemfile** and then do bundle install.

b. Add this line to **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

c. Add this line **to app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

d. How to use it inside your form or wherever you want to use:

Add an input field to show your calendar like:

```
<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >
```

and then call js on this input field by:

**Add this code at the bottom of your application.js**

```
  $(document).on("click","[data-behaviour~=datepicker]",function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
  });
```

**Edit**

As per discussion you have not included javascript tag inside your layout file. You need to solve it by adding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to call js on input, I added this script above and doeasn't work

Comment: @user3742883 updated my answer with js code too in order to incorporate for turbolinks (if you are using rails 4)

Comment: still nothing pop up after clicked text field :(

Comment: @user3742883 can you post your view, application.js with updated code and exactly the way they are now? Post them in question

Comment: @user3742883 write `//= require_self` before  `//= require_tree .` and also add `alert("working");` before `$(this).datepicker();` and see if it's alerting. Check for any errors in developer console as well

Comment: @user3742883 Can you see the alert window popup?

Comment: @user3742883 run same code inside your developer console and then try it. You know how to use it?

Comment: no, no :( i am really, really new in ruby, never met this again and need this to finish my school project :) because they want rails web app :)

Comment: @user3742883 it has nothing to do with ruby. if you are using chrome then do  for Windows/Linux `F12, Ctrl + Shift + I` for mac `Cmd + Opt + I` and if you are using firefox then for windows/linux `Ctrl + Shift + I` for mac `Cmd + Opt + I`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55751/discussion-between-user2675613-and-user3742883).

Comment: Ok, I am there :) I didn't know you think about this :P

Comment: @user3742883 click on the link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55751/discussion-between-user2675613-and-user3742883. I can't solve it by telling you each and every step here in comments

Comment: This solution uses a completely different gem than the OP was using. (DateTimePicker != DatePicker).  The way they interact with a form is entirely different.

Comment: @JosephK ah my bad. I have updated my answer but the problem was related to javascript tag not included in layout file

Answer (score 0):

b. Add this line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass

```
...
*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
*= require_tree .
```

and at the bottom of this

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```